# Undefined property: stdClass::$idarticulo

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estoy viendo en youtube un curso para aprender laravel, pero me atoré en uno de los videos, me marca el siguiente error:

```
    Whoops, looks like something went wrong. 2/2
ErrorException in 64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php line 63: Undefined property: stdClass::$idarticulo (View: C:\CursoLaravel\sisVentas\resources\views\compras\ingreso\create.blade.php)
in 64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php line 63
at CompilerEngine->handleViewException(object(ErrorException), '1') in PhpEngine.php line 44
at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\CursoLaravel\sisVentas\storage\framework\views/64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'personas' => array(object(stdClass)), 'articulos' => array(object(stdClass)))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59
at CompilerEngine->get('C:\CursoLaravel\sisVentas\resources\views/compras/ingreso/create.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'personas' => array(object(stdClass)), 'articulos' => array(object(stdClass)))) in View.php line 149
at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
at View->renderContents() in View.php line 85
at View->render() in Response.php line 53
at Response->setContent(object(View)) in Response.php line 201
at Response->__construct(object(View)) in Router.php line 1085
at Router->prepareResponse(object(Request), object(View)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
```

Y muchas líneas más. Hay otro error (me parece que es lo mismo)

```
1/2
ErrorException in 64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php line 63:
Undefined property: stdClass::$idarticulo

in 64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php line 63
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined property: stdClass::$idarticulo', 'C:\CursoLaravel\sisVentas\storage\framework\views\64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php', '63', array('__path' => 'C:\CursoLaravel\sisVentas\storage\framework\views/64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php', '__data' => array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'personas' => array(object(stdClass)), 'articulos' => array(object(stdClass))), 'obLevel' => '1', '__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'personas' => array(object(stdClass)), 'articulos' => array(object(stdClass)), 'persona' => object(stdClass), 'articulo' => object(stdClass))) in 64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php line 63

at include('C:\CursoLaravel\sisVentas\storage\framework\views\64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php') in PhpEngine.php line 42

at PhpEngine->evaluatePath('C:\CursoLaravel\sisVentas\storage\framework\views/64985b6b79521ec2a9edfc6aab57cf2831fffa17.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'personas' => array(object(stdClass)), 'articulos' => array(object(stdClass)))) in CompilerEngine.php line 59

at CompilerEngine->get('C:\CursoLaravel\sisVentas\resources\views/compras/ingreso/create.blade.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'personas' => array(object(stdClass)), 'articulos' => array(object(stdClass)))) in View.php line 149

at View->getContents() in View.php line 120
```

Lo poco que puedo entender es que, por alguna razón, no encuentra el $idarticulo, pero de acuerdo al código escrito, sí está ahí (sale de un foreach)

```
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Artículo</label>
                <select name="pidarticulo" class="form-control selectpicker" id="pidarticulo" data-live-search="true">
                    @foreach($articulos as $articulo)
                        <option value="{{$articulo->idarticulo}}">{{$articulo->articulo}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

La variable `$articulos` se manda desde el controlador en la función "create":

```
public function create()
{
    $personas=DB::table('persona')->where('tipo_persona','=','Proveedor')->get();
    $articulos=DB::table("articulo")
        ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(codigo, " ",nombre) as articulo', 'idarticulo'))
        ->where('estado','=','Activo')
        ->get();
    return view('compras.ingreso.create',["personas"=>$personas,"articulos"=>$articulos]);
}
```

Ya le di vueltas al código varias veces y no encuentro qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal. ¿Podrían echarle un vistazo, a ver si dan con la solución? No pegué todo el código porque me parece que es demasiado, pero si necesitan más info edito el tema.

¡Gracias!

Comment: Tenés mal un paréntesis en el select `->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(codigo, " ",nombre) as articulo', 'idarticulo'))` tendría que ser `->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(codigo, " ",nombre) as articulo'), 'idarticulo')`

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Eres un Dios!!!!!!! Publícala como respuesta para que la marque. Muchísimas gracias!!!

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ  No me deja eliminar la pregunta, supongo porque ya tiene dos respuestas. Publica tu respuesta para que ganes tu reputación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal ubicado un paréntesis en el select de tu consulta, y `'idarticulo'` te está quedando dentro del `raw` en vez de como otra columna a seleccionar:

```
->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(codigo, " ",nombre) as articulo', 'idarticulo'))
```

tendría que ser:

```
->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(codigo, " ",nombre) as articulo'), 'idarticulo')
```

Answer (score 0):

perdón lo poco técnico, pero creo que es $articulo->articulo.
Hace mucho no uso laravel, pero siento que podría ser eso

Answer (score 0):

El error es bastante claro, te esta diciendo que la propiedad `idarticulo` no existe en tu objeto `$articulo` y ese esta instanciado en tu vista.

Tu error puntual se encuentra en esta sentencia.

```
{{$articulo->idarticulo}}
```

Revisa que el atributo este bien escrito.

Answer (score 0):

te lo soluciono:

```
$articulos=DB::table('articulo as art')
            ->select(DB::raw('CONCAT(art.codigo," ",art.nombre) AS articulo'), 'art.idarticulo')
            ->where('art.estado','=','Activo')
            ->get();
```

te faltó el cierre de paréntesis al lado de `art.nombre) AS articulo')` para ese mismo proyecto te recomiendes uses articulo as art y para luego diferenciar cuando hagas las uniones mas adelante una mala explicación en el tutorial, ya que luego a mitad de videos te encuentras con que hay cosas no funcionan y es porque no explico que en un momento reacomodó las querys

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si explicas tu aporte, checa [answer]